# DataTriggers: What's wrong?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, controltemplate, datatrigger

I'm trying to use a custom skin on my `ToggleButton`. Here's my `ToggleButton`:

```
<ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource OnTemplate}" IsChecked="True" >
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource OnTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource OffTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Here are the two templates:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="OnTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="ToggleOn.png" />
        <TextBlock>On</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="OffTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="ToggleOff.png" />
        <TextBlock>Off</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This doesn't seemingly work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply removing the `Template="{StaticResource OnTemplate}"` from your button definition.  Local values trump values from trigger/style setters.

Also, you will either need to use a regular `Trigger` instead of a `DataTrigger`, or you will need to set `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` on your `DataTrigger` bindings.  I recommend the former.

Comment: This works. Triggers is the thing I need. Plus local value of Template was actually blocking the Style from implementing its change. Thanks everyone, especially Mike.

Comment: Also, can I move both `ControlTemplate`s inside my `<ToggleButton.Resources>` section? I tried that but then I can't reference them in `Value="{StaticResource OnTemplate}"` part.

Comment: I believe you can, but the resources will need to appear in Xaml *before* they are referenced.  It probably didn't work before due to your referencing of the template in the button declaration.

Comment: Last but not the least, the Trigger appears to fire AFTER the `Checked` event of my ToggleButton, which creates an undesirable feel. Can I some make it such that the Template is applied BEFORE the `Checked` event's handler starts executing?

Comment: Not as such, but you could add a trigger on `IsPressed` to, for example, adjust the margins to shift the contents to the bottom/right to simulate a "pressing down" effect.  I often use this effect for "borderless" buttons (adjust `Margin` to `1,1,-1,-1`).

Comment: I'm basically showing a dialog when ToggleButton's IsChecked is true. So in my case the dialog appears on the screen while the ToggleButton hasn't yet applied the ON template.

Comment: Try calling `UpdateLayout()` first; if that fails, you can force the dispatcher to update the layout by using `Dispatcher.Invoke()` with a priority of `Input` or lower to perform the logic that shows your dialog.